# Memory allocation issue with fortran and C program

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, fortran, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have a fortran code that I am trying to get to work for my research purposes. The fortran code passes an integer variable and an integer size into a C program that will allocate memory. The code consists of a pointer "iarrays" that point to "arrays(1)". I get a segmentation fault with the following message:
[Segmentation Fault](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BD7ui.png)

The following is the fortran Code:

```
      subroutine initmem
c-----initial memory setup

      pointer ( iarrays , arrays(1) )
      
c-----allocate pointer memory for blocks and set blocks index pointers
      lpoint(0,1) = 0
c-----first call to lpoinst computes storage requirements
      call lpoinst
c-----Returns kplast = 1138280 which is the No. of bytes for pointered arrays. I have verified lpoinst works correctly
      nwdinc = kplast - lpoint(0,1)
```

[Array lpoint after lpoinst function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1iuL.png)

```
c-----nbytaddr = 1
      call getmem (lpoint(0,1), (nwdinc*nbytaddr))
c-----Note:getmem is a fortran file only used to check if memory is allocated. I have not included the code in this post.  

c-----getmem.F calls C program memalloc(lpoint(0,1), (nwdinc*nbytaddr)) 
c-----memalloc.c code attached below
c-----value of lpoint(0,1) = -1431465968

c-----second call to lpoinst sets pointers with updated lpoint(0,1).
      call lpoinst
```

[Array lpoint after lpoint(0,1) was updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0P6cA.png)

```
      iarrays = lpoint(0,1)
      isize = nwdinc / addrinc
      do 100 i=1,isize
        arrays(i) = zero
 100  continue

      return
      end
```

Here is the C program memalloc.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifdef _CRAY
int MEMALLOC (nextptr, size)
#else
#ifdef POST_UNDERSCORE
int memalloc_ (nextptr, size)
#else
int memalloc (nextptr, size)
#endif
#endif

int *size;
int *nextptr;
{
  void *ptr;
  printf("Size Address:%d Size Value: %d \n", size, *size);
  printf("nextptr Address:%d nextptr Value: %d \n", nextptr, *nextptr);
  printf("ptr before hexa: %p ptr before int: %d \n", (void *) ptr, (int *) ptr );
  if (*nextptr == NULL) {
    if ((ptr = (void *) malloc (*size)) == NULL) {
      return(-1);
    }
  }
  else {
    if ((ptr = (void *) realloc (*nextptr, *size)) == NULL) {
      return(-1);
    }
  }
  printf("ptr after hexa: %p ptr after int: %d \n", (void *) ptr, (int *) ptr );
  *nextptr = (int) ptr;
  printf("nextptr Address:%d nextptr Value: %d \n", nextptr, *nextptr);
  return (0);
}
```

[Print statements in memalloc.c](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBuyj.png)

The pointer iarrays is set to a negative value. Can the value of that pointer be negative? Why is not able to access the memory for arrays(i)? Can someone help me get through this segmentation fault?

Thank you!

Comment: OT: Please note that both `malloc` and `realloc` already return `void *`. It's unclear to me what do you expect from `printf("ptr before hexa: %p ptr before int: %d \n", (void *) ptr, (int *) ptr );`

Comment: The declarations for "int *size;" and "int *nextptr;" should not be setting between your function declaration (e.g. "int memalloc (nextptr, size)" and the curly braces.  Is this a typo?

Comment: @NoDakker That is K&R C. It predates the first C standard. It was correct way back then. It is now deprecated and ill advised.

Comment: I don't have an answer, am just doing some random speculation. That is old code. I don't know how you are building it or what platform you are running it on. Computer now have a lot more memory than they did then. This code is using an int to hold an address. People used to do that. What is the size of an int in the implementation that you are using & what is the size of a memory address?

Comment: And the negative value of iarrays is probably due to the value having wrapped at least once because it is bigger than INT_MAX.

Comment: @Bob__ I was just printing them out to display the results before and after memory allocation. (void *) gives the value in hexadecimal and (int *) gives the numerical value. I did this because the value returned to fortran code is an integer.

Comment: @AviBerger The size of int is 4 bytes. I am using a PGI compiler version 2020.4. Does it have to do anything with running on a 64 bit computer vs whatever it was run on back in those days? Sorry, I am trying to get this code to work for a mechanical simulation project and I am not very familiar with computing issues.

Comment: That could be it. 4 byte int and 8 byte addresses. An address won't fit in an int on your platform. There was never a guarantee an address would fit in an int, though in particular cases it did. It seems you will have to change the interface to pass back something bigger.

Comment: Your `memalloc_` is _ancient_! The trailing `_` and the K&R prototypes. Without ansi prototypes, the args will default to `int` instead of (e.g.) `size_t` so you'll probably have a mismatch between 4 and 8 byte values when compiling on a modern 64 bit machine.

Comment: @AviBerger How do I do that? I had once tried *nextptr = (long int) ptr. But that did not work. How do I change the interface to pass back something big?

Comment: @CraigEstey How can I avoid this mismatch?

Comment: I don't know. It has to work on both the C and Fortran sides and I don't know your development tools or what interfacing between C & Fortran with them is like.  On the C side, returning a`void *` instead of an `int` would probably be the best choice, but I don't know if that's usable from the Fortran side. It sounds like you are using a recent compiler, so re @CraigEstey's excellent comment, you should be able to redo the K&R style function declarations to use ANSI prototypes instead. I would recommend doing so.

Comment: Please use tag [tag:fortran]. You also do not use tags like [tag:c89] but just [tag:c]. Your program wwas not written with portability in mind and so porting it to 64 bit will be hard work. There is no sipmple answer with a few changes, you will have to rewrite a lot of code. On the Fortran side you *might* be succesful with just compiling the code for 64 bit integers (consult your compiler) but real modernization would be much more involved. This bodge cannot be done in C because the system libraries have fixed int size.

Comment: The real modernization would of course just use dynamic memory capabilities introduced in Fortran 90 and later. A bodge could just get rid of the C code and use the non-standard memory allocation procedures that Fortran compilers often supply for work with integer pointers (aka. Cray pointers).

Comment: Note your code if at least Fortran 90 with the non-portable pointer extension - question edited to reflect this.

Comment: Switch to ansi prototypes (what you're used to--they've been standard since the mid 1990s). So, remove all the `#ifdef` stuff before the first `{'` line. Replace with: `int memalloc (int *nextptr, int *size)`