# Memory address truncation issue during dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c, fortran, dynamic-memory-allocation, truncated

I have a fortran subroutine (getmem.F) that uses a C program (memalloc.c) for dynamic memory allocation. The following subroutine and functions are a part of a very old and large code that was used for research purposes. I am compiling on a 64 bit machine and I am using a PGI compiler 2020.4 version. The following is the fortran code.

```
      subroutine getmem(ptr, size)

c-----get pointered memory

cdir$ nolist
      include 'common.h'
      include 'inputcom.h'
cdir$ list

      integer memalloc, memfree
      integer ptr, size, ierr0

c-----allocate 'size' words of memory and send back pointer in 'ptr'

      print *, "Value of ptr and size before memory allocation"
      print *, "ptr:", ptr               ! The value of ptr is 0
      print *, "size:", size             ! The value of size is 1138280

      if (size .lt. 0) then
        ierr0 = memfree (ptr)
      else
        ierr0 = memalloc (ptr, size)
      endif

      print *, "Value of ptr and size after memory allocation"
      print *, "ptr:", ptr               ! The value of ptr is -1431465968 (This is incorrect 
                                         ! value which is the decimal from signed 2's complement for 2863501328)
      print *, "size:", size             ! The value of size is 1138280

      if (ierr0 .ne. 0) then
        call writemsg ('Unable to get memory.')
        write (buffer, 100) size
  100   format ('GETMEM:  size is ', i15, '.')
        call writemsg (buffer)
        stop 'getmem'
      endif

      return
      end
```

Here is the C code memalloc.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h> /* Added by Surya */

int memalloc_ (int *nextptr, int *size)

{
  void *ptr;

  printf("Address of nextptr:%p \nValue of nextptr: %d \n", nextptr, *nextptr);
  /*Output: Address of nextptr: 0x1687ad0 
            Value of nextptr: 0 */

  /* Before Memory Allocation */

  printf("Address pointed by ptr (Value stored in ptr): %p \n", (void*)ptr);
  /*Output: Address pointed by ptr (Value stored in ptr): 0x7fffffff8b40 */   
         
  if (*nextptr == NULL) {
    if ((ptr = (void *) malloc (*size)) == NULL) {
      return(-1);
    }
  }
  else {
    if ((ptr = (void *) realloc (*nextptr, *size)) == NULL) {
      return(-1);
    }
  }
  /* After memory allocation using malloc() */

  printf("Address pointed by ptr (Value stored in ptr): %p \nValue when printed as a long integer %ld \n", (void*)ptr, (int*)ptr);
  /* Output: Address pointed by ptr (Value stored in ptr): 0x2aaaaaad9010
             Value when printed as a long integer: 46912496308240 */

  *nextptr = (int) ptr;

  printf("Address of nextptr:%p \nValue of nextptr: %d \n", nextptr, *nextptr);
  /* Output: Address of nextptr: 0x1687ad0
             Value of nextptr: -1431465968  */

  printf("Value of nextptr in long format: %ld \n", *nextptr);
  /* Output: Value of nextptr in long format: 2863501328  */

  return (0);
}
```

When I do hexadecimal to decimal conversions and vice versa (https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-decimal.html), I notice what the issue is. When we do (int) ptr. The hexadecimal value of ptr = 0x2aaaaaad9010 (decimal value is 46912496308240) is truncated to aaad9010 (decimal value is 2863501328). When this gets passed back into the fortran77 code as ptr, the ptr which is later used as pointer to point to memory is unable to find the variable and its value. How do I fix this issue so that the truncation does not happen in the C program?

P.S. This is very old style of coding but it is part of a much larger code (Validated with experiments) of my research.

Comment: Here `*nextptr = (int) ptr;` it seems that you try to store a pointer in an int. On most 64 bit systems a pointer is 64 bit and int is 32 bit. So that would be a truncation.

Comment: So how can I fix that. I need to pass the address stored in ptr back to the fortran77 code.

Comment: My guess is that the function paramet is to be `int **nextptr`

Comment: You mean declare the parameter as `int **nextptr` and replace `*nextptr = (int) ptr` as just `*nextptr = ptr` ?

Comment: yes.... I don't know about the fortran stuff.... but C function seems to update `nextptr` to be another int-pointer... In C that means you pass a pointer-to-pointer-to-int

Comment: I tried that but it returned a segmentation fault with realloc(). That was another question. I tried by changing the function argument to other data types such as long *nextptr or long int *nextptr. When I do that I get the segmentation fault for realloc(). Any idea about that?

Comment: `.... %p \n", (void*)ptr);` is rather bad.... `ptr` is uninitialized....

Comment: `malloc (*size)` hmmm.... maybe correct but.... if `*size` represents the number of integers then you need `malloc (*size * sizeof(int))`

Comment: When you changed the function to take `**nextptr` did you also changed the way you called it?

Comment: You got good pieces of advice in your last question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73751059/memory-allocation-issue-with-fortran-and-c-program  Did you use any of it? On 64 bit, an integer is not going to be able to hold an address in default settings. You cannot just change the C side, you must also change the the Fortran side. And the easiest is to just ditch the C code altogether and use Fortran features for dynamic memory.

Comment: Check this out: https://ideone.com/BzjaZk It's your code with a few changes. Most important is that the function takes a double pointer. I also removed the illegal print of pointers using %d. The code would work in pure C... I'm not sure about the fortran part

Comment: OT: You don't need `if (*nextptr == NULL) {` to select between `malloc` and `realloc`. Just use `realloc` directly. When `realloc` is called with NULL, it works just like `malloc`. So you can simplify your code....

Comment: @SupportUkraine When I do `*size *sizeof(int)`, the memory address stored in ptr changes but the problem still persists. I did not change how it is called in the fortran function when I changed it to **nextptr. I will try to work something over there.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава Yes, I tried some of those fixes. Actually, In fortran, when I define one of the variables that is passed into memalloc as the *nextptr from integer to integer*8 it works. But this would require me to change every subroutine and function that uses memalloc in the code. I can explore that option if nothing here works.

Comment: You **MUST** use 64 bit types to hold the address. Hoping for the best with 32-bit integers is complete nonsense. Completely hopeless. If you are really desperate, try compiler options that promote all integers to 64-bit. Explore the manual of your compiler. Which compiler do you use?

Comment: " I did not change how it is called in the fortran function when I changed it to **nextptr." Well... as I said I don't know the fortran stuff but.... If you change a C functions parameters, you would also need to change the code calling the function. Things have to match...

Comment: I am using a PGI compiler 2020.4 version. When you say we MUST use a 64 bit types to hold the address, what do you mean by that? How do I make the*nextptr into a 64 bit instead of 32 bit? As I had mentioned in one of the comments above, when I use long or long in for *nexptr while defining the argument, I get a sementation fault for realloc().

Comment: I concur with @VladimirFГероямслава, with the current code there's no other way than passing INTEGER*8 from the fortan side and promoting all the "int" to "long long" on the C side. Another possibility would be to generate a static 32 bits executable binary if your compiler has such an option (but this assumes that all the needed libraries have a 32 bits version that is available).

Comment: You do not get to choose whether an address is 32-bit or 64-bit. All addresses in modern computers are 64-bit. You could compile in 32-bit instead, if your compiler allows it. But you would be subject to the 4GB memory limitation. If that is enough, you can try it. But you must do it in both C and Fortran. First check, how to promote integers in your Fortran compiler. Then check how to compile the code for e2

Comment: ...Then check how to compile the code for 32-bit. Try both. Read your compiler's manual. Read how pointers work. Read how you can allocate memory in Fortran 90. It should by **by far** the best solution. What your code does is a bodge. If you show us what your Fortran cose actually does, including the include files, we might even be able to show how to do it. It might actually be very simple. Or not, if the memory is shared using common blocks. But we do not know.

Answer (score 1):

- (Bug) In order to pass something back to the caller through a parameter, you must use a pointer to pointer.
- (Bug) The `(int) ptr` cast is non-portable and fairly obviously the culprit of your narrowing conversion.
- (Bug) You can't print the contents of `ptr` before assigning it to point somewhere. You can't print the contents pointed at by `nextptr` before assigning a value. You cannot print the value of a null pointer.
- (Design) There is no reason to pass `size` as a pointer since you don't change it inside the function.
- (Design) Casting the result of `malloc` to `void*` is pointless.
- (Design) Casting from `void*` to `void*` is pointless.
- (Design) `realloc` behaves like `malloc` if passed a NULL pointer. Since your function apparently assumes that the passed pointer is always initialized as a null pointer during the first call, you can utilize that to simplify the code.
- (Possible bug) Alternatively, if the passed pointer *isn't* initialized, your code is completely bugged - you cannot call `realloc` with an uninitialized pointer as parameter.

With all the bugs and clutter removed, your code might look something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// NOTE: *nextptr must be initialized to null outside this function!
int memalloc_ (int** nextptr, int size)

{
  void *ptr;
  printf("Address of *nextptr:%p\n", (void*)*nextptr);
         
  ptr = realloc(*nextptr, size); 
  if (ptr == NULL) {
      return -1;
  }
  *nextptr = ptr;
  printf("Address pointed by ptr (Value stored in ptr): %p\n", ptr);
  printf("Address of nextptr:%p\n", (void*)*nextptr);
  return 0;
}
```

This should compile even in old C90.

Comment: This will compile, but will not solve the ultimate problem, that the obsolete Fortran code won't be able to use that if it continues to use `integer` to store the pointer value.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава That may be so, but these bugs mentioned here need to be fixed regardless.

Comment: @Lundin I would't change too much the code apart from fixing the main problem. Although non standard and non portable, according to the OP it was working well in a past context. So either it's possible to make it work again in the current context with minimal changes, or the whole code (including the Fortran side, maybe completely removing the C side) should be modernized. For instance replacing `int *size` with `int size` in the C arguments requires adding an interface on the Fortran side, with C binding stuff and the `value`  attribute for this argument.

Comment: Good point, passing the `size` suddenly by value will break the code that calls this and would only be solved by Fortran 2003 interfaces. But using those with this kind of allocation would be beyond bizarre, it would be the Daily WTF level.

Comment: Similarly I don't see the point changing `int** nextptr`to `int* nextptr`: in both case this is an address, which requires a 64 bits integer on the Fortran side. I would keep `int* nextptr` in the argument, replace `*nextptr = (int)ptr` with `*nextptr = (long long)ptr`, and use `integer*8 ptr` on the Fortran side. Still non standard and non portable, but should work.

Comment: @PierU It has to be a pointer type or otherwise it's back to square one. `uintptr_t` would be another option, in case we can verify that the OP is actually using a standard C compiler and not some C90 thing. If they don't have standard C, they don't have the more incorrect `long long` type either.

Comment: @Lundin you're right, the first argument has to be a pointer to a 64 bits object if one wants to get an `integer*8` on the Fortran side. It can be either `long long *nextptr` or `int **nextptr` (both are OK, I have tested). Or `int64_t *nextptr` (better, as it is fully consistent with the `integer*8`). And in the code `*nextptr = (int64_t)ptr`. I have tested, and I get consistent results like this.

Comment: @PierU Those are all more or less non-portable. "I have tested" is a silly thing to say when discussing portable code, you have tested on one or two of all thousands different, existing systems. `uintptr_t` is the correct integer type for this purpose, period. You can't come to that conclusion by testing, but by reading the guarantees made by the C standard.

Comment: @Lundin My suggestions on the C code are as standard as yours. They are not fully portable as I assume that 1) an address can be casted in a `long long` and 2) a C `long long*` can be implicitely bound to a Fortran `integer*8`: non portable but quite reasonnable. Your proposal is standard C but not portable either, because you now want to implicitely bind a C `unintptr_t*` to... I don't know what in Fortran because you are focusing on the C part only. This is a C-Fortran problem, which can not be solved by looking at the C side only.